# In Manila, what are the strengths of focusing on investing in cheap black market wares and controlling the landing outcomes of the punts?

Tags: manila

The harbor master is obviously a critical role toward selecting and initializing the punts (boats), and the pirate and large and small pilots are the only remaining fine-tuning mechanisms to the landing outcomes of the boats. The wharf and shipyard bets seem short term incidental, more gambling bets, to me and less longer term ones such as investments in the black market value of the wares.

My general thoughts are to put a premium on obtaining harbor master early as long as the cost is not too prohibitive and to obtain as many shares across the board of wares at 5 pesos, then shift to giving up harbor master and driving up the price of bids (as long as I can be sure I won't accidentally win it), then focusing on being the pilots and pirates as a means to drive the boats to the wharf or shipyard of my preference to stall the game as long as possible and increase the black market value of my shares.  The ideal would be to encumber as many of my shares as possible and use that equity to manipulate the outcome either by being a reasonably priced harbormaster or placing accomplices on the pilot or pirate spaces.

This feels like a solid long term goal with occasional bets on the punts, shipyard and wharf (although these seem much more short term and apparent to everyone in terms of their likelihood, risk, etc, so they are either more long shot or quickly taken when more of a sure thing).

The key to whether this approach becomes viable lies behind whether the cost to be harbormaster justifies the potential gain in the wares. A 5 peso ware maybe reaching 20 pesos becomes a break-even proposal if you pay 15 pesos just to obtain harbormaster and costs of 5 and 2/5 for pirate and pilots make it seem more likely that players who grab up spots on the punts will come out positive more than this strategy might.